# What will happen to the limits of this integration?

Tags: integration, statistics, definite-integrals

This is a joint probability distribution function (PDF)
f(x,y) = $C(x^2 + y)$  and the limits are $x>0$ and $0 < y < (1-x^2)$

We have to calculate the marginal PDF of Y, i.e. f(y).
I get that we will integrate the joint function with the limits of x. But can't figure out what they will be. And what will happen to dx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that your joint PDF can be written as 
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y) = c\cdot(x^2+y)1_{x>0}(x)1_{0<y<(1-x^2)}(x,y)
$$
where $1_A(\cdot)$ designates the indicator function over the set $A$, namely,
$$
1_A(a) = \begin{cases}
1,\ \text{if}\ a\in A\\
0,\ \text{else} 
\end{cases}.
$$
Now note that
$$
1_{x>0}(x)1_{0<y<(1-x^2)}(x,y) = 1_{0<x<\sqrt{1-y},0<y<1}(x,y)
$$
Thus, (for $0<y<1$, other wise $f_Y(y)=0$)
\begin{align}
f_Y(y) &= \int_{\mathbb{R}}c\cdot(x^2+y)1_{x>0}(x)1_{0<y<(1-x^2)}(x,y)dx\\
&=\int_0^{\sqrt{1-y}}c\cdot(x^2+y)dx
\end{align}
and from here it is easy to continue.